# Memory handling in C++ classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, memory

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class abc{
    private:
        int a;
        string s;
    public:
        abc(int x,string y) {
            a=x;
            s=y;
        }
        ~abc() {
            cout<<"destructor for abc called\n";
        }
};

class def{
    private:
        int *a;
        string *s;
    public:
        def(int x, string y) {
            a = new int;
            s = new string;
            *a=x;
            *s=y;
        }
        ~def() {
            delete a;
            delete s;
            cout<<"destructor for def called\n";
        }   
};

int main() {
    abc *obj1 = new abc(10,"hello");
    delete obj1;
    def *obj2 = new def(20,"world");
    delete obj2;
    abc obj(30,"anything");
}
```

1. Where obj, obj1 and obj2 will be stored? In a heap or in a stack. I know that the heap space contains all objects that are created, but stack contains any reference to those objects. Still, I'm confused.
2. After deleting obj1, destructor for class abc will be called and free the space for the object but the space occupied for that integer and string stored in the object will be freed or still occupied? Like in the case when obj2 is deleted, it is specified to free the space for integer and string both.
3. How is destructor called for obj when I'm not deleting that object and if I do not delete obj1 or obj2 explicitly, then why destructor is not called?

Comment: You must initialize `a` and `s` in `class def` before applying `delete` to them.

Comment: "I know that the heap space contains all objects that are created, but stack contains any reference to those objects." - No, that's plain wrong. `obj1` is a pointer stored on the stack. It points to an `abc` object stored on the heap. `obj2` is a pointer stored on the stack, pointing to a `def` object stored on the heap. `obj` is stored on the stack.

Comment: "After deleting obj1, destructor for class abc will be called and free the space for the object but the space occupied for that integer and string stored in the object will be freed or still occupied?" The integer is inside the object, so when the memory for the object gets freed the memory for the integer is freed. Same thing happens with the string object, but the string object contains a pointer to the actual string which gets freed by the destructor of the string object.

Comment: @bessiethecow A local simple variable like `obj1` actually need't be stored on the stack, it may be stored in a CPU register as well.

Comment: "Like in the case when obj2 is deleted, it is specified to free the space for integer and string both." - They will both be freed because you deleted them in the constructor. "How is destructor called for obj when I'm not deleting that object." - Objects with automatic storage duration are automatically destroyed when they go out of scope.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes. To be precise, the `obj1` has automatic storage duration. The memory is automatically allocated and freed when following its scope.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Thanks for your kind replies. Now I understood how memory allocation works here.

Comment: If you use new, and don't delete, it doesn't get destructed. (this is why you're not supposed to use new in modern usage) As far as where they are stored in memory, or when the OS recycles that memory for new allocations, does it matter to you as the programmer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't actually have a concept of "the stack" or "the heap".  C++ only cares about object lifetimes, not where the implementation chooses to store those objects.

In this case, there are two lifetimes at play:

- `new abc()` and `new def()` create objects with *dynamic lifetime*

  - These objects will live until a pointer to them is passed to `delete`
- `obj1`, `obj2`, and `obj` have *automatic lifetime*

  - These objects will live until the end of their enclosing scope

Keep in mind that when I say `obj1` and `obj2` have automatic lifetime, I mean the *pointers* `obj1` and `obj2` only.  The objects they point to (those returned by `new`) have dynamic lifetime and will live until explicitly `delete`d.  If the pointers `obj1` and `obj2` go out of scope before the objects they point to are deleted, those dynamic objects will continue to live with no way to ever `delete` them.

---

> 1. Where obj, obj1 and obj2 will be stored? In a heap or in a stack.

`obj`, `obj1`, and `obj2` all have automatic lifetime.  On most systems this means they're stored on the system stack or in a CPU register (or both).

The objects pointed to by `obj1` and `obj2` have dynamic lifetime.  On most systems such objects are stored in memory allocated from a system heap.

> I know that the heap space contains all objects that are created, but stack contains any reference to those objects. Still, I'm confused.

This statement is not true.  Objects can have automatic or dynamic (or static, which I haven't covered here) lifetime.  C++ has a fairly broad definition of what an "object" is.  An `int`, an `abc`, and an `abc*` are all types of object, and any of them can have any lifetime depending on how they're created.

> 2. After deleting obj1, destructor for class abc will be called and free the space for the object but the space occupied for that integer and string stored in the object will be freed or still occupied? Like in the case when obj2 is deleted, it is specified to free the space for integer and string both.

The lifetime of all of an object's data members ends when that object's lifetime ends.  When the `abc` object pointed to by `obj1` is destroyed, `obj1->a` and `obj1->s` will also be destroyed.

When the `def` object pointed to by `obj2` is destroyed, by default only the *pointers* `obj2->a` and `obj2->s` would be destroyed.  That's why you have to explicitly `delete` any dynamically-allocated objects those pointers point to in `def`'s destructor.

> 3. How is destructor called for obj when I'm not deleting that object.

`obj` has automatic lifetime, and thus will be destroyed when control reaches the end of its enclosing scope (the end of `main`, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

> Where obj, obj1 and obj2 will be stored? In a heap or in a stack. I know that the heap space contains all objects that are created, but stack contains any reference to those objects. Still, I'm confused.

They're all local objects to the function that cease to exist when the function ends. So they'll typically all be on the stack.

> After deleting obj1, destructor for class abc will be called and free the space for the object but the space occupied for that integer and string stored in the object will be freed or still occupied?

No. Since `obj1` is a function local, it is destroyed when the function ends. When you do `delete obj1;` that does not actually delete `obj1`, since `obj1` still exists and is valid. It deletes the object that `obj1` points to, not `obj1` itself.

> Like in the case when obj2 is deleted, it is specified to free the space for integer and string both.

When the object `obj2` points to is deleted, that invokes that object's destructor.

> How is destructor called for obj when I'm not deleting that object and if I do not delete obj1 or obj2 explicitly, then why destructor is not called?

Since `obj` is of type `abc` and `abc` has a destructor, its destructor is called when `obj` goes out of scope. However, `obj1` and `obj2` are of type `abc *`. There is no destructor for `abc *`, so nothing to do when they go out of scope.